# Using something like a relay to convert from a 12 V car signal to a 5 V external odometer signal

Tags: relay

I want to add an external odometer (like a Brantz Rallymeter or a Terratrip 303) to a vintage car. This car already has a wire with a +12 V signal for it's electronic odometer, something like one signal for each wheel turn.

The problem is that either Brantz and Terratrip machines use 5 V signals. The connections on these odometers is easy: they have three wires, one for +5V, one for -5V, and one with the signal (+5V, if I remember well).

I can convert the signal from the car using a simple relay, but I think that it won't last very long, because it has to be changing states really fast (and I'll be really noisy).

How can I build this simple schematic without using a mechanic relay?

[image: Schema with a simple relay]

P.S.: Keep in mind that I'm a noob about electronics. I know how to use a soldering iron, but not much more..

**Edit 2**: There are some reasons because I want to build this conversor/adapter. The first is because the original Brantz adapter (BR5) is expensive and due the Brexit they won't sell to the UE because it costs less than 150UKP. The other reason is because I love to learn things :)

As I already told, the idea of using a relay is because I can "excite" the relay with the signal from car's odometer, and use the external odometer signal, without converting it, only allowing the signal to pass or not. But I'm unsure if a mechanical relay will last long...

Finally, there is a link to a standard Brantz speedometer cable sensor (the BR1): https://www.brantz.co.uk/_files/ugd/f2f644_1fb0552e6ce44f7db7ab6e806f9ec124.pdf. Here you can see that the sensor receive +5V and earth (brown and green wires), and returns a signal to the blue wire. What I want is to build something like this but using the signal from the electronic speedometer from the car.

Comment: A resistor divider can do the drop? Or a resistor and a zener would offer some protection to the odometer.

Comment: @Ralph I don't know. A resistor will be enough to convert the signal from +12V to +5V?
But if the signal is -5V (I have to check it; I'm 95% sure that it's +5V) then I need some other schema, isn't it?
And what's a Zener? Which is it's function?

Comment: Yes, but then you couldn't work it out with a relay either.

Comment: You may look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider

Comment: Can you _edit your question_ with a link to the documentation you have that mentions the +5V, -5V and signal wires?  I suspect that the "-5V" is actually the 5V return (i.e., ground on a negative-ground car).  Note that using a voltage divider is fraught with difficulties if the existing wiring is just switching the battery voltage on and off -- +12V on a car is notoriously _not_ just +12V; you don't want to run it into delicate electronics without some protective circuitry.

Comment: You may also want to try a forum that's specific to your sort of rallying -- chances are that someone else has been in your position, and that a solution specific to your proposed equipment has already been found.  Or, talk to Brant and Terratrip and see if they have suggestions -- with luck, they'll either tell you how to rewire your sensor to work with their stuff, or they'll have adapters they'll sell you.

Comment: @TimWescott I've expanded the question. As you say, the -5V is the 5V return. I didn't know that there wasn't a -5V wire; I always supposed that the ground wires were -5V... As I told, I'm just a novice...

Comment: Did this to drive a rev counter for a petrol engine from a Diesel engine - diesels don’t have sparks. So a Hall effect sensor, 2 magnets and simple amplifier as well as a voltage control worked well. Don’t ask for a diagram - it was 40 years ago. But may give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an optocoupler module, to do both the level conversion and provide isolation.  You can get these units very cheaply on eBay with suitable voltage levels.